# How to add quotations around existing text in DataGrip?

Tags: datagrip

When I need to add 'quotation mark' to an existing text in some intelligent editors (eg. vscode), I can select the text and type `'`, this will add quotation mark around the text. When I try this approach in DataGrip, it replace the text. Is there any way to make this easier?

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution myself in DataGrip settings:

```
Settings - Editor - General - Smart Keys - 
☑️ Surround selection on typing quote or brace.
```

I hope this might be useful for people who are new to DataGrip.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might need *CtrL+Alt+T* → *Surround with* action. There you can configure any surrounding you want.

Comment: Glad to know this surround option, on mac, it's `cmd-option-t`. Thanks!